# Select randomly few Rows of the same ID in the same table (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I'm trying to select **randomly** few rows for each Id stored in one table where these Ids have multiple rows on this table. It's difficult to explain with words, so let me show you with an example :

Example from the table :

```
Id  Review
1   Text11
1   Text12
1   Text13
2   Text21
3   Text31
3   Text32
4   Text41
5   Text51
6   Text61
6   Text62
6   Text63
```

Result expected :

```
Id  Review
1   Text11
1   Text13
2   Text21
3   Text32
4   Text41
5   Text51
6   Text62
```

In fact, the table contains thousands of rows. Some Ids contain only one Review but others can contain hundreds of reviews. I would like to select 10% of these, and select at least once, all rows wich have 1-9 reviews (I saw the `SELECT TOP 10 percent FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()` includes the row even if it's alone)
I read some Stack topics, I think I have to use a subquery but I don't find the correct solution.

Thanks by advance.

Regards.

Comment: random Review for each Id?

Comment: If you only want 10 % of the rows for each ID, why would you have 2 rows with ID 1 in your expected result ?

Comment: For example : for Id with 100+ reviews, select  randomly 10%. And for the Ids with <10 reviews, select randomly 10% (1 row in fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table(Id int, Review char(6))
INSERT @t values
(1,'Text11'),
(1,'Text12'),
(1,'Text13'),
(2,'Text21'),
(3,'Text31'),
(3,'Text32'),
(4,'Text41'),
(5,'Text51'),
(6,'Text61'),
(6,'Text62'),
(6,'Text63')

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
  id, Review,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by newid()) rn, 
  count(*) over (partition by id) cnt
   FROM @t
 )
 SELECT id, Review
 FROM CTE
 WHERE rn <= (cnt / 10) + 1
```

Result(random):

```
id  Review
1   Text12
2   Text21
3   Text31
4   Text41
5   Text51
6   Text63
```

Comment: Hi T-Clausen, I've tried with more significant table and it seems to be OK :) Thanks a lot.